# Node.JS for Background Video delivery

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, video, background

My apologies if this question is misguided, or if what I'm saying doesn't make sense, as I'm somewhat uninitiated to the nodejs world. I've been cruising pretty easily with just plain PHP and Apache for some time now, until I discovered ZURB Foundation's stack w/ Handlebars and SASS, along w/ NPM.

Currently, I'm using simply an HTML5  tag to deliver background video to a page: http://159.203.191.97/sii003. I'm currently on Apache and considering utilizing node and the ProxyPass feature of AWS to serve my content. Would utilizing JS help me save speed on loading/playback of the background video?

It's rather crucial to the user experience and I am curious whether I would be able to load video more quickly utilizing nodejs. I realize that bandwidth and processing speed can create bottlenecks no matter what I do.

Comment: `Would utilizing JS help me save speed on loading/playback of the background video?` probably not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are planning on Video delivery, use the [AWS Native Service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/TutorialStreamingFlowplayer.html)s for Video Storage(Use S3) and Streaming(Use CloudFront) while using your NodeJS API to provide access permission(Using [Signed URLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html)) if its private content.

This will provide a highly scalable and cost effective solution for media delivery.